# C++ getting the path of a file for System

Tags: c++

I have a project in JavaScript, it needs to be run with node and output to a file so I decided to use C++, I need to use the System command.

I am using Visual Studio BTW

I need to link to another files path in the .exe so the System command can use it. Example: If I have an exe that contains Generator/main.js, how can I get a path to it so the exe file is portable. How can I return the path of a contained file? Is this possible?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Generator!";
    cin.get();
    // This needs to be run from CMD, how do I link to Generator in the project folder?
    system("node Generator/main.js > %userprofile%/Desktop/Gen.txt");
    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT** How can I copy files from an exe into a file, such as the desktop?

Comment: Why do you think you need C++ for this? Why not just, um, execute Node.JS directly?

Comment: Resources embedded into the application obviously have no "path". You need to research the resource framework you're using. Then use a pipe. Probably nothing to do with `system`, but WinAPI functions.

Answer (score 0):

Although your question is somewhat self-contradictory, it sounds like you're just looking for something in the same directory as the executable, not stored inside the executable itself. For that, [`GetModuleFileName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683197.aspx) can help.

The general idea is something on this order:

```
char buffer[MAX_PATH];

GetModuleFileName(NULL, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
```

If you really have stored something inside the executable itself, you'd use the resource functions (`FindResource`, `LoadResource`, `LockResource`, etc.) to get access to that data.